# Beautifulsoup doesn't scrape data consistently every time

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape player's name and their ratings on this website:
https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1549539/LiveStatistics/England-Premier-League-2021-2022-Brentford-Arsenal.

After scraping then I put the data in a csv. But, it does not scrape consistently. I probably have to run the script more than once(2-5 times) to get it to scrape the data. This also happens when I try to scrape for other matches. For example, if I get the data from 3 matches, probably it will only scrape the first match and doesn't scrape the remaining data for other pages. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

match_link='https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1549539/Live/England-Premier-League-2021-2022-Brentford-Arsenal.'

driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(match_link)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

Players_list=[]
Player_rating=[]

try:
            player_name=soup.select('a.player-link span.iconize.iconize-icon-left')
            player_rating=soup.select('td.rating')

            #print('------------getting player name and ratings-----------')
            for nme in player_name:
                #print(nme.text)
                Players_list.append(nme.text)
            for rat in player_rating:
                #print(rat.text)
                Player_rating.append(rat.text)
except:
            print('NO ELEMENT')

Players_list=pd.DataFrame(Players_list)
Player_rating=pd.DataFrame(Player_rating)

        
df=pd.concat([Players_list,Player_rating],axis=1)
df.to_csv('brentford-arsenal.csv')
```

It doesn't raise an error. It just returns an empty results (meaning the data wasn't scraped). The elements are rightly selected but it's the inconsistency of the script is the problem.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: If I follow that link and inspect the page, there aren't any anchor tags with class `player-link` unless click into the Player Statistics tab. You'll have to use your webdriver to click the link and wait for the tab to load before you grab the source.

Comment: Oh actually I went to this link : (https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1549539/LiveStatistics/England-Premier-League-2021-2022-Brentford-Arsenal

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an expicit [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the page to render.

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1549539/LiveStatistics/England-Premier-League-2021-2022-Brentford-Arsenal'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'player-table-statistics-body'))
    )
```

If you always want to use the latest chrome driver, then the new [web manager](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager) auto-detects when a new driver is available, downloads, and caches it. To install manager: `pip install webdriver-manager`

You can do the selection directly in Selenium so won't need to reparse the HTML using BeautifulSoup. Here's the complete solution using ChromeDriverManager.

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1549539/LiveStatistics/England-Premier-League-2021-2022-Brentford-Arsenal'

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

# web driver goes to page
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'player-table-statistics-body'))
    )

Players_list = []
Player_rating = []

for nme in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.player-link span.iconize.iconize-icon-left'):
    Players_list.append(nme.text)
for rat in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.rating'):
    Player_rating.append(rat.text)
data = {'name': Players_list, 'rating': Player_rating}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('brentford-arsenal.csv')
```

Output:

```
                      name rating
0               David Raya   7.60
1            Ethan Pinnock   7.57
2          Kristoffer Ajer   6.71
3           Pontus Jansson   6.92
4              Sergi Canós   8.78
5               Rico Henry   6.79
6       Christian Nørgaard   7.67
7            Vitaly Janelt   6.74
...
33            Reiss Nelson   6.04
34          Mohamed Elneny      -
35               Karl Hein      -
36           Cédric Soares      -
37         Héctor Bellerín      -
38  Ainsley Maitland-Niles      -
39             Rob Holding      -
```

If the page rendering still returns inconsistent results then can either add `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` after the WebDriverWait call or create a custom EC condition that waits until finds same number of players and rankings.

Comment: It sill returns empty results. I also tried using `time.sleep(3)` but it still returns nothing. It sometimes does return the results but not always and inconsistent.

Comment: @aliffnabil - replace implicitly_wait() with WebDriverWait... EC.presence_of_element_located to ensure the desired element is populated. That should work every time.

Comment: Using WebDriverWait didn't get anything. But I increased the implicitly_wait(25) and tried to scrape 5 matches but it only manage to scrape 4 matches. Also, that only worked once and never again.

Comment: @aliffnabil - Getting 39 matches on every fetch with wait=10. Make sure you have the latest Chrome browser and using ChromeDriverManager for the latest chrome driver.

Comment: I tried in addition to changing the parse library but it still is inconsistent with getting the data. I even tried increasing the wait until wait=50

Comment: @aliffnabil - Did you try using ChromeDriverManager with WebDriverWait() rather than time.sleep? See updated answer with complete example.

Comment: @CodeMonkey- Looks like I got the solution. Using time.sleep solves the problem